# How to run the google map sample v2?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-android-api-2

I am writing an android apps which require the use of Google Map.
I use Eclipse and have downloaded the SDK.
I then import the Google Play Service and the maps sample inside
and Eclipse have successfully compile and run in an emulator.
However, while running, it didn't work!!
It closed the apps after a few second on the main page, and none of the fragments(objectS)
were shown...

I have not change anything except adding android.support-v4.jar
and change meta-data in manifest for my Google key.

I have tried to:

- run on emulator and real device(Samsung S2 LTE)
- use both registered certificate and debug certificate, and have asked for API access on Google to get a key
- use different versions of Eclipse: Kepler, Helios and the one downloaded from developer

But none of them work.

Does anybody know what's happening? What shall I do to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must have followed all these steps to import the Google play services library project and its map samples which are given in this url :-

**https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro**

If you have correctly imported the project and library by following above steps and still your map is not working then it may be because of the reason that the google play service are not working on your device on which you are running tha samples. You have to reboot your device so that the google services start working.

Comment: You are right, I have followed it.
I have tried reboot it and confirmed the google play service is on and google play store works.
but the problem is still the same.